Is there a way to approximate the potential voltage sag?
I am building a load cycler to charge and discharge batteries. The part that is measuring the voltage of the battery is done via the analog pin of the Arduino.

It is able to measure the voltage to some extent, but I seem to be encountering some voltage sag where if I remove the battery and leave it alone the voltage rises. Thus, the voltage being measured by the analog pin is not entirely accurate.
Is there any way of calculating or approximating the expected voltage sag from a circuit like this?

Can you measure voltage when you are not loading it? Have you considered separate wire for voltage measurement? If you have shared ground, you will halve your voltage drop over the wire. Also, consider thicker wires to minimize IR drop.

Sag or rise (not both together).

How are you measuring the voltage? Is there just a direct connection from battery terminals to MCU ground and analog input, or some voltage divider? How often you take a voltage sample, and how is the ADC configured, like internal clocks and sampling time, etc, if even configurable?

Battery voltage is strongly dependant on its history. If you were charging or discharging the battery, then 'leave it alone', you would expect the voltage to change.
As the battery is being charged or discharged, chemical concentrations in the electrolyte adjacent to the active plates change. This effect is called polarisation, and minimising it is one of the key engineering problems to be overcome when designing a practical battery. Once you 'leave the battery alone', those concentrations start to diffuse back to an equilibrium state, changing the cell voltage slightly as they do so.
Another element of history is the battery temperature. Any current flow will warm the battery, and it will of course cool down once left alone. Cell voltage is also temperature dependant.
This is why cell voltage alone is such an unreliable indicator of the state of charge of a battery, and there is a thriving market in the more complicated coulomb-counting 'gas-gauge' type devices for battery monitoring.
Cell voltage is of use at the extremes of state of charge, to prevent over-charge or over-discharge.

If the compliance voltage of the charger current source is 5V, then the voltage measured will be 5V with the battery disconnected (no current).
Depending on the charging protocol, with the battery connected the voltage will measure less than 3V for a discharged lithium battery, and measure about 4.2V for one that is fully charged.
The Battery University has a short discussion of the charge/discharge and mid point voltages.
As the battery charges, the measured voltage will be in between. If the battery is removed at any time during charging the voltage will rise to the compliance voltage.
Trying to predict the voltage with the battery inserted is difficult for any particular time in the charging cycle, as discussed by Nick_UK in his answer.

If you want to eliminate any effect of the connection and wire resistance, turn the charging off for a short time and then measure the voltage.
